# How to add a smaller image to larger one at a specific coordinate?

Tags: image-processing, options

How can I **add** a foreground image (smaller) to a background image (larger) by specifying the central pixel coordinate of the smaller image with respect to the background? It seems `ImageAdd` only gives you very basic options (e.g. top, right, etc.).

Added Notes:
I'm adding a sparse and noise-free image to a very large and noisy background. `ImageCompose`, blends (takes a weighted average). This creates a very ugly footprint of the smaller image on the background. This doesn't happen with `ImageAdd` which is missing coordinate option, unfortunately.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
img1 = ExampleData[{"TestImage", "Lena"}];
img2 = ImageResize[ImageCrop[ExampleData[{"TestImage", "Mandrill"}], 
   {Full, 150}, Bottom], 200];
img3 = Graphics[Text@Style[Uncompress@"1:eJwdysEJgDAMBdCO8t1A3cKreuwlbaIVJIFGkW4ven28Ltm8xBDCpLiKwAuxPbAN6ajsv1kWUlSj6oj9MK5FFH4zi57tH0wN+ZQvkDKa3RXSxJEL6S4voyoixg==", "Panel", White, 20, 
  Background -> Transparent]]

ImageCompose[ImageCompose[img1, {img2, .5}, {296, 240}], img3, {250, 450}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**Update:** To avoid blending of the two images you can use the fifth argument of `ImageCompose` (see [Documentation >> ImageCompose >> Details](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ImageCompose.html)

[image: Mathematica graphics]
[image: Mathematica graphics]
[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
ImageCompose[img1, img2, {296, 240}, {Center, Center}, {0, 1, 1}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**Update 2:** Two approaches to position the foreground image using `ImageAdd`:

```
padding[pos_, im1_, im2_] := Transpose[{pos - Round[ImageDimensions[im2]/2], 
   ImageDimensions[im1] - pos - Round[ImageDimensions[im2]/2]}]

ImageAdd[img1, ImagePad[img2, padding[{300, 240}, img1, img2]]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Alternatively, one can use the trick mentioned in a comment by @mpourrah, create an empty image with dimensions of `img1` and use `ImageCompose`  to position `img2`, and then `ImageAdd` it to `img1` to get the same picture as above:

```
ImageAdd[img1, ImageCompose[Image[Array[0&, ImageDimensions[img1]]], img2, {300, 240}]]
```

> same picture

Comment: I like your artwork! However, I'm adding a sparse and noise-free image to a very large and noisy background. `ImageCompose`, blends (takes a weighted average). This creates a very ugly footprint of the smaller image on the background. This doesn't happen with `ImageAdd` which is missing coordinate option.

Comment: @mpourrah, does it help if you change `{img2, .5}` to `{img2, 1}`?

Comment: @mpourrah, you can also use the fifth argument of `ImageCompose` to avoid blending: e.g.,  `ImageCompose[img1, img2, {296, 240}, {Center, Center}, {0, 1, 1}]` (see [Documentation >> ImageCompose >> Details](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ImageCompose.html))

Comment: Unfortunately, none of the fifth options of the `ImageCompose` do what adding does. What ended up working was the following: 

1. Create an empty image (all zeros) with the same dimensions as the background image. 

2. Using `ImageCompose`, merge the foreground image to the specific location. 

3. Add the result to the background image using `ImageAdd`.

Comment: @mpourrah, please see update.

Comment: Yes, that works pretty well. Thank you for following up and answering my question in such a creative way.